# How to remove a native plugin

Tags: plugins, trigger.io

Does anyone know if there is a way to remove a [native plugin](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.4/modules/native/index.html#native-plugins) from the Trigger.IO toolkit? None of my applications depend on these test plugins, and I'd just like to remove them to clean up the 'Manage Plugins' section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't currently remove plugins, you'll be able to in a future version of the Toolkit. If you really want to remove some you can send an email to support@trigger.io and someone will be able to do it for you.

Comment: How long do you think it will be until this is feature available?